# $m^{2^n} - 1$ is 'good'.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> For integers $a$ and $n > 0$, call $a$ $n$-expressible if it can be written as a sum of distinct positive divisors of $n$. A natural number $n$ is called good if $a$ being $n$-expressible implies that $a-1$ is also $n$-expressible. Find all integers $m\geq2$ for which there exists an integer $n$ such that $m^{2^n} - 1$ is good.

I've attempted to rewrite $m^{2^n} -1$ using difference of two squares recursively:
$$m^{2^n}-1 =\left(m^{2^{n-1}}+1\right)\left(m^{2^{n-2}}+1\right)\ldots(m^2+1)(m+1)(m-1)$$

If $n$ is $(m^{2^n} - 1)$-expressible then $n$ can be expressed as a sum of the divisors above? I tried considering $n = m^k$ for some $k$. Now do we sum the divisors of $m^{2^n} - 1$?

$$m-1+m+1+m^2+1+\ldots +1+m^{2^{n-2}}+1+m^{2^{n-1}} $$$$= n-1 + 2m + m^2 + m^4 + \ldots + m^{2^{n-2}}+1+m^{2^{n-1}}$$

By geometric series we get:
\begin{align*}
2m+n-1 + \frac{m^2\left((m^2)^n - 1\right)}{m^2-1} &= 2m+n-1 + \frac{(m^n-1)(m^n+1)}{(m+1)(m-1)}\\ 
&= 2m+n-1 + \frac{(m^{n-1}+m^{n-2}+\ldots+1)(m^n+1)}{m+1}
\end{align*}

I'm not sure if this is even correct or if it's at all helpful, but I'm not sure how to proceed from this.